# Solutions for a system of congruence equations

Tags: elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations, congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem

I have a system

$$
\begin{cases}
x \equiv 7 \pmod{15} \\
x \equiv 14 \pmod{33}
\end{cases}
$$

How can I show that the system does not have any solutions?

I know that the first implies that $x = 7+15k$ and the second implies that $x = 14+33m$ and $\text{gcd}(15,33) = 3$.

## Edit

Trying to show that another system has no solutions
$$
\begin{cases}
x \equiv 14 \pmod{98} \\
x \equiv 1 \pmod{28}
\end{cases}
$$

I have $\text{gcd}(98,28) = 14$.

From the system I get $x = 14+98k$ which implies that $x \pmod{14} = 0$. From the other congruence equation I get $x = 1+28m$ which implies that $x \pmod{14} = 1$. Therefore the system has no solutions.

But why am I using the trick by finding $x \pmod{\text{gcd}(n_1,n_2)}$ for each congruence equation? Is it just to find a number which can cancel out both $98$ and $28$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** what is the value of $x$ modulo $3$?

Comment: $0$, $1$ or $2$ depending on the value of $x$. Should I first equate the two equations and find a expression for $x$?

Comment: Are you sure that it depends on the value of $x$?  We know that $x = 7 + 15k$, what does that tell you?

Comment: That $x$ is $7$ and a multiple of $15$. No matter the value of $k$ it will always be divisible by $3$ so $x$ is always equal to $7$ and $x \pmod{3} = 7 \pmod{3} = 1$. The same goes for $x = 14+33m$ where $14 \pmod{3} = 2$. Now I have $7 \pmod{3} = 1 \neq 14 \pmod{3} = 2$ and therefore the system has no solutions. Am I right?

Comment: Right.  So, you've just concluded that for every solution $x$, $x \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.  You've also concluded that for every solution $x$, $x \equiv 2 \pmod 3$.

Comment: Right.  The two statements cannot hold simultaneously.

Comment: Why are you writing $x \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ and $x \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$? Is it better to always simplify the expressions as much as possible? If I update my question with another example, will you verify that I'm doing it correctly? :-)

Comment: It's more important for your answers to be readable then for them to be short.  I find that having multiple $\pmod 3$'s makes things messy, or possibly ambiguous.

Comment: Yes, you are doing your question correctly.  You're using that trick because it turns out that there is a solution if and only if that trick gives you the same result from all equations.

Comment: In the case of the second problem, we could have made our lives easier by checking modulo 2.

Answer (score 1):

For the first system:

"I know that the first implies that x=7+15k and the second implies that x=14+33m and gcd(15,33)=3."

We try to solve the system of equations! we get $7+15k=14+33m \rightarrow (15k-33m)=7 \rightarrow 3(5k-11m)=7$, which is impossible as 7 is not divisible by 3.

Additionally, $x=7+15k$ means that $x \cong 1 (mod 3)$. 
$x=14+33m$ means that $x \cong 2 (mod 3)$. Contradiction, hence no solutions.

The second system can be similarly solved by considering it mod 2.

Comment: I just don't get why you can conclude that from $3(5k-11m) = 7$. I know that my conclusion should include that I can't find any integers $k$ and $m$ that make the equation true. But I don't see why it's enough to say that $7$ and $3$ is not divisible.

Comment: 3 times any integer is divisible by 3, right? We know that 5k-11m is an integer. Hence 3(5k-11m) must be divisible by 3. Since 3(5k-11m)=7, 7 must be divisible by 3, which is absurd.

Comment: I see. Of course. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

***Consider***

$x  \equiv a (mod n)$
$ x  \equiv a(mod m)$

***Then the  above has a solution only if gcd(m,n) divides gcd(a,b).
Here gcd(15,33)=3 and gcd(7,14)=7.
Here the given equation has no solution***

Comment: This is wrong.  Take
$$
x \equiv 2 \pmod 3\\
x \equiv 2 \pmod 6
$$
$3$ does not divide $2$.  However, the system clearly has a solution.

Comment: Can you please tell me the solution?

Comment: look at either of the other two answers

Comment: Or do you mean the solution to the system I presented? How about $x=2$